# SQL INSERT with INNER JOIN from list of constant strings

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a SQL Server 2012 Query which inserts a constant list of permission names, e.g. "ViewUsersPermission", "ModifyUsersPermission" into the table RolePermissions.

This table has two columns: A "RoleID" which is a foreign key to the Roles table, and a varchar column "PermissionTypeName".

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RolePermissions] ([PermissionTypeName], [RoleID])

   SELECT 'ViewUsersPermission' AS [PermissionTypeName]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ModifyUsersPermission' AS [PermissionTypeName]
   UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ViewRolesPermission' AS [PermissionTypeName]

   INNER JOIN   (SELECT [RoleID] FROM [dbo].[Roles]
                WHERE [Name] = 'Administrator')
```

I am looking for a better solution. I want to specify a list of permissions types like:

```
SELECT FROM 'ViewUsersPermission', 'ModifyUsersPermission', 'ViewRolesPermission'
```

instead of using the `UNION ALL` construct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are on at least 2008

```
SELECT RoleName
FROM   (VALUES('ViewUsersPermission'),
              ('ModifyUsersPermission'),
              ('ViewRolesPermission')) V(RoleName)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint using the `VALUES` construct!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the help from Martin, the complete SQL INSERT statement looks the following:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[RolePermissions] ([PermissionTypeName], [RoleID])
    SELECT [PermissionTypeName], [RoleID] FROM (VALUES('ViewUsersPermission'),             
        ('ModifyUsersPermission'), ('ViewRolesPermission')) V([PermissionTypeName])
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Roles] AS [Role]
        ON [Role].[Name] = 'Administrator'
```