# MySQL list of values as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking for an alternative to this in MySQL
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13494329

SQL query:

```
SELECT tempId
FROM (
        VALUES(1),(2),(3)
    ) V(tempId)
```

Result:

```
tempId
  1
  2
  3
```

Comment: To what purpose? Why you need other solution? And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For equivalent of **Table Value Constructor** in `MySQL` you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT tempId
FROM (
        SELECT 1 AS tempId
        UNION ALL SELECT 2
        UNION ALL SELECT 3
    ) V
```